# Remove elements in a component of a list that already appeared in earlier components in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list with each component being a numeric vector. There are some common numbers in the components. Here is an example:

```
ls <- list(c(7, 4, 9), c(5, 9, 2, 19), c(3, 13, 4, 2))
```

Component 2 has its second element already appeared in component 1. Component 3 has its 3rd and 4th element already appeared in component 1 and 2, respectively. I want to remove the elements in later component that already appeared in earlier component. For the specific example, I want `ls2 <- list(c(7, 4, 9), c(5, 2, 19), c(3, 13))`.

I wish to write an R script that automatically executes the above task, which generalizes to other lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setdiff`:

```
ls <- list(c(7, 4, 9), c(5, 9, 2, 19), c(3, 13, 4, 2))

foo <- function(x) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)[-1]) {
    x[[i]] <- setdiff(ls[[i]], unlist(ls[seq_len(i - 1)]))
  }
  x
}

ls2 <- foo(ls)
#[[1]]
#[1] 7 4 9
#
#[[2]]
#[1]  5  2 19
#
#[[3]]
#[1]  3 13
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `setdiff()`, on each element to remove all previously seen elements. First, we need to make the list of previously seen elements:

```r
ls <- list(c(7, 4, 9), c(5, 9, 2, 19), c(3, 13, 4, 2))

accumulated <- Reduce(union, ls, accumulate = TRUE)
accumulated
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 7 4 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  7  4  9  5  2 19
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  7  4  9  5  2 19  3 13
```

Then, for each element of the list, we compare it to the accumulated list of previously seen elements. Note that we need to separate the first element of the list:

```r
c(ls[1],
  lapply(seq_along(ls)[-1],
         \(i) setdiff(ls[[i]], accumulated[[i - 1]])))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 7 4 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  5  2 19
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  3 13
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `unlist` and check `duplicated` values, and then `relist` and remove duplicates with indexing:

```r
dup <- relist(duplicated(unlist(ls)), skeleton = ls)
mapply(function(x, y) x[!y], ls, dup)

# [[1]]
# [1] 7 4 9
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  5  2 19
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  3 13
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `stack` + `subset` + `unstack`

```
unstack(
    subset(
        stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))),
        !duplicated(values)
    )
)
```

which gives

```
$`1`
[1] 7 4 9

$`2`
[1]  5  2 19

$`3`
[1]  3 13
```